# Is there a way to hide bundle id and apple developer team from public GitHub projects?

Tags: ios, swift, github

I want to make my project open source but don’t really like the idea of my apple developer name and app bundle id being public. Is there a way I can hide it?

Ive not made an open source project before so open to all suggestions.

Comment: Easiest is probably to create a fresh repo without your developer name / bundle ID in it. Deleting it from the commit history seems like it'd be annoying.

Comment: Creating a brand new repo, and making an initial commit after having removed any keys/ids you don't want public should do the trick.

Thumbsup for being cautious when open sourcing something!

Answer (score 9):

By default, Xcode stores your product bundle identifier and your development team identifier as build settings in your [`xcodeproj`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Projects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH5-SW1), along with all the other details of your project structure.

You can tell Xcode to [load build settings from a file](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-a-build-configuration-file-to-your-project/) with the suffix `xcconfig`. By moving just those settings to an `xcconfig` file, and telling Git to ignore that file, you can publish your repo without publishing those settings.

Follow these steps to move those two settings out of your `xcodeproj` and into an `xcconfig` file:

1. Add a new file to your project. Use the ‘Configuration Settings File’ template:

   [image: Xcode document template selection window. I have typed “config” into the search field. The template titled “Configuration Settings File” is selected.]

   Name the file `project.xcconfig`. Add it to the top-level group (which is your project itself) and don't add it to any targets.

   [image: Xcode project navigator. It shows all the files created automatically by the iOS project template, plus the new project.xcconfig file.]
2. Xcode should open `project.xcconfig` automatically. If it doesn't, click it in the project navigator to open it.
3. Open the project editor in a separate editor pane. You can create a separate editor pane by clicking this button in the top-right corner of the editor:

   [image: Xcode's “Add Editor” button]

   Then click on your project itself (the top-level group) in the project navigator to open the project editor:

   [image: Xcode's project navigator. The project item, named “HideDevInfo”, is selected.]
4. Make sure the project itself is selected in the project editor's outline:

   [image: Project editor's outline showing the project itself is selected.]
5. In the Configurations section, click the chevron next to “Debug” to show its child, which is the project itself. Then, on the project row, click the popup menu in the “Based on Configuration File” row and choose “project”. Do the same for the “Release”. When you're done, it should look like this:

   [image: Project editor showing that the “project” configuration file has been chosen for both Debug > HideDevInfo and Release > HideDevInfo.]
6. Click on your [target](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009328-CH4-SW1) (your app) in the project editor's target list. Then click the “Build Settings” tab. Then click “All” and “Levels”.

   [image: The project editor, showing the HideDevInfo target's build settings, set to “All” and “Levels”.]
7. In the search field at the top right, type `product_bundle_identifier`. Double-click the green box in the table that shows your product bundle identifier:

   [image: The green box containing the product bundle identifier, which in this example is com.dqd.HideDevInfo.]
8. Xcode opens a popover where you can edit the product bundle identifier. Press <kbd>⌘C</kbd> to copy the identifier to the clipboard.

   [image: The popover with a text editor showing the product bundle identifier.]
9. In the other editor pane, which should still be editing `project.xcconfig`, add a line at the end with the text `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER =`  and paste in the identifier using <kbd>⌘V</kbd>.
10. Click on the “Product Bundle Identifier” row label in the build settings editor to select the row. Press the delete key.

    [image: The “Product Bundle Identifier” row in the build settings editor.]

    Xcode removes the setting from your `.xcodeproj`, leaving it only in the `project.xcconfig` file. If you deselect the row in the build settings editor, it looks like this:

    [image: “Product Bundle Identifier” row in the build settings editor. It is empty in the columns for the target and project, and is set in the “Config.File” column.]

    You can see that Xcode is now reading the setting from `project.xcconfig`.
11. Repeat the process for the “Development Team” setting. Search the build settings for `development_team`. Copy its value to `project.xcconfig`, using the setting key `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM`. Then select the “Development Team” row in the build settings editor and press the delete key to remove the setting from your `.xcodeproj`. Your `project.xcconfig` should now look like this:

    ```
    //
    //  project.xcconfig
    //  HideDevInfo
    //
    //  Created by Rob Mayoff on 1/24/23.
    //

    // Configuration settings file format documentation can be found at:
    // https://help.apple.com/xcode/#/dev745c5c974

    PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.dqd.HideDevInfo
    DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = SECRET123X
    ```
12. Clean your build folder (from the menu bar, choose Product > Clean Build Folder). Build and run your app. Make sure it still works.
13. Edit your `.gitignore` file. (If you don't already have one, create a new empty file at the top of your Git work tree.) Add a line that says `project.xcconfig`.
14. Commit your changes.

Please note that if this is not your first commit in the Git repository, your bundle identifier and your team identifier are still visible in the older commits. You may want to squash all your commits down to a single commit to remove them. There are ways to edit your commit history to remove those settings from all prior commits, but you'll need to post a separate question if you want to try that.

Comment: in Step 9, $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) worked for me instead of just PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER. I was trying to change the bundle identifier from DevOps pipeline and $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) worked fine.